# Series temporais, como eliminar os espaços entre períodos ausentes no ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso apresentar dados climáticos durante um período de avaliação, **porém a lapsos temporais**, conforme observado na Figura 1, utilizando os dados (`exe2`) e o script (1). Naturalmente o `ggplot` plota o eixo x como dados contínuos, preciso seja criado (cortes) para aproximar os períodos (Figura 2), e ou  elimine mesmo esses espaços.

Figura 1: Exemplo normal
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Figura 2: Exemplo de possível modelo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dados do exemplo:

```
exe2<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 
18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 
18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 
18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 
18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 
18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18601, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 18602, 
18602, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 
18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 
18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 
18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 
18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 
18603, 18603, 18603, 18603, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 
18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 
18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 
18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 
18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 
18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18604, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 18605, 
18605, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 
18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 
18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 
18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 
18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 
18637, 18637, 18637, 18637, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 
18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 
18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 
18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 
18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 
18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18638, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 18639, 
18639, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 
18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 
18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 
18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 
18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 
18640, 18640, 18640, 18640, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 
18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 
18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 
18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 
18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 
18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18641, 18675, 18675, 
18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 
18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 
18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 18676, 
18676, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 
18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 
18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 
18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 
18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 
18677, 18677, 18677, 18677, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 
18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 
18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 
18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 
18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 
18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18678, 18679, 18679, 
18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 
18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 
18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 
18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 
18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 18679, 
18679), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(1607126400, 1607162400, 
1607164200, 1607166000, 1607167800, 1607169600, 1607171400, 1607173200, 
1607175000, 1607176800, 1607178600, 1607180400, 1607182200, 1607184000, 
1607185800, 1607187600, 1607189400, 1607191200, 1607193000, 1607194800, 
1607196600, 1607130000, 1607131800, 1607198400, 1607200200, 1607202000, 
1607203800, 1607205600, 1607207400, 1607209200, 1607211000, 1607133600, 
1607135400, 1607128200, 1607137200, 1607139000, 1607140800, 1607142600, 
1607144400, 1607146200, 1607148000, 1607149800, 1607151600, 1607153400, 
1607155200, 1607157000, 1607158800, 1607160600, 1607212800, 1607248800, 
1607250600, 1607252400, 1607254200, 1607256000, 1607257800, 1607259600, 
1607261400, 1607263200, 1607265000, 1607266800, 1607268600, 1607270400, 
1607272200, 1607274000, 1607275800, 1607277600, 1607279400, 1607281200, 
1607283000, 1607216400, 1607218200, 1607284800, 1607286600, 1607288400, 
1607290200, 1607292000, 1607293800, 1607295600, 1607297400, 1607220000, 
1607221800, 1607214600, 1607223600, 1607225400, 1607227200, 1607229000, 
1607230800, 1607232600, 1607234400, 1607236200, 1607238000, 1607239800, 
1607241600, 1607243400, 1607245200, 1607247000, 1607299200, 1607335200, 
1607337000, 1607338800, 1607340600, 1607342400, 1607344200, 1607346000, 
1607347800, 1607349600, 1607351400, 1607353200, 1607355000, 1607356800, 
1607358600, 1607360400, 1607362200, 1607364000, 1607365800, 1607367600, 
1607369400, 1607302800, 1607304600, 1607371200, 1607373000, 1607374800, 
1607376600, 1607378400, 1607380200, 1607382000, 1607383800, 1607306400, 
1607308200, 1607301000, 1607310000, 1607311800, 1607313600, 1607315400, 
1607317200, 1607319000, 1607320800, 1607322600, 1607324400, 1607326200, 
1607328000, 1607329800, 1607331600, 1607333400, 1607385600, 1607421600, 
1607423400, 1607425200, 1607427000, 1607428800, 1607430600, 1607432400, 
1607434200, 1607436000, 1607437800, 1607439600, 1607441400, 1607443200, 
1607445000, 1607446800, 1607448600, 1607450400, 1607452200, 1607454000, 
1607455800, 1607389200, 1607391000, 1607457600, 1607459400, 1607461200, 
1607463000, 1607464800, 1607466600, 1607468400, 1607470200, 1607392800, 
1607394600, 1607387400, 1607396400, 1607398200, 1607400000, 1607401800, 
1607403600, 1607405400, 1607407200, 1607409000, 1607410800, 1607412600, 
1607414400, 1607416200, 1607418000, 1607419800, 1607472000, 1607508000, 
1607509800, 1607511600, 1607513400, 1607515200, 1607517000, 1607518800, 
1607520600, 1607522400, 1607524200, 1607526000, 1607527800, 1607529600, 
1607531400, 1607533200, 1607535000, 1607536800, 1607538600, 1607540400, 
1607542200, 1607475600, 1607477400, 1607544000, 1607545800, 1607547600, 
1607549400, 1607551200, 1607553000, 1607554800, 1607556600, 1607479200, 
1607481000, 1607473800, 1607482800, 1607484600, 1607486400, 1607488200, 
1607490000, 1607491800, 1607493600, 1607495400, 1607497200, 1607499000, 
1607500800, 1607502600, 1607504400, 1607506200, 1610236800, 1610272800, 
1610274600, 1610276400, 1610278200, 1610280000, 1610281800, 1610283600, 
1610285400, 1610287200, 1610289000, 1610290800, 1610292600, 1610294400, 
1610296200, 1610298000, 1610299800, 1610301600, 1610303400, 1610305200, 
1610307000, 1610240400, 1610242200, 1610308800, 1610310600, 1610312400, 
1610314200, 1610316000, 1610317800, 1610319600, 1610321400, 1610244000, 
1610245800, 1610238600, 1610247600, 1610249400, 1610251200, 1610253000, 
1610254800, 1610256600, 1610258400, 1610260200, 1610262000, 1610263800, 
1610265600, 1610267400, 1610269200, 1610271000, 1610323200, 1610359200, 
1610361000, 1610362800, 1610364600, 1610366400, 1610368200, 1610370000, 
1610371800, 1610373600, 1610375400, 1610377200, 1610379000, 1610380800, 
1610382600, 1610384400, 1610386200, 1610388000, 1610389800, 1610391600, 
1610393400, 1610326800, 1610328600, 1610395200, 1610397000, 1610398800, 
1610400600, 1610402400, 1610404200, 1610406000, 1610407800, 1610330400, 
1610332200, 1610325000, 1610334000, 1610335800, 1610337600, 1610339400, 
1610341200, 1610343000, 1610344800, 1610346600, 1610348400, 1610350200, 
1610352000, 1610353800, 1610355600, 1610357400, 1610409600, 1610445600, 
1610447400, 1610449200, 1610451000, 1610452800, 1610454600, 1610456400, 
1610458200, 1610460000, 1610461800, 1610463600, 1610465400, 1610467200, 
1610469000, 1610470800, 1610472600, 1610474400, 1610476200, 1610478000, 
1610479800, 1610413200, 1610415000, 1610481600, 1610483400, 1610485200, 
1610487000, 1610488800, 1610490600, 1610492400, 1610494200, 1610416800, 
1610418600, 1610411400, 1610420400, 1610422200, 1610424000, 1610425800, 
1610427600, 1610429400, 1610431200, 1610433000, 1610434800, 1610436600, 
1610438400, 1610440200, 1610442000, 1610443800, 1610496000, 1610532000, 
1610533800, 1610535600, 1610537400, 1610539200, 1610541000, 1610542800, 
1610544600, 1610546400, 1610548200, 1610550000, 1610551800, 1610553600, 
1610555400, 1610557200, 1610559000, 1610560800, 1610562600, 1610564400, 
1610566200, 1610499600, 1610501400, 1610568000, 1610569800, 1610571600, 
1610573400, 1610575200, 1610577000, 1610578800, 1610580600, 1610503200, 
1610505000, 1610497800, 1610506800, 1610508600, 1610510400, 1610512200, 
1610514000, 1610515800, 1610517600, 1610519400, 1610521200, 1610523000, 
1610524800, 1610526600, 1610528400, 1610530200, 1610582400, 1610618400, 
1610620200, 1610622000, 1610623800, 1610625600, 1610627400, 1610629200, 
1610631000, 1610632800, 1610634600, 1610636400, 1610638200, 1610640000, 
1610641800, 1610643600, 1610645400, 1610647200, 1610649000, 1610650800, 
1610652600, 1610586000, 1610587800, 1610654400, 1610656200, 1610658000, 
1610659800, 1610661600, 1610663400, 1610665200, 1610667000, 1610589600, 
1610591400, 1610584200, 1610593200, 1610595000, 1610596800, 1610598600, 
1610600400, 1610602200, 1610604000, 1610605800, 1610607600, 1610609400, 
1610611200, 1610613000, 1610614800, 1610616600, 1613557800, 1613559600, 
1613561400, 1613563200, 1613565000, 1613566800, 1613568600, 1613570400, 
1613572200, 1613574000, 1613575800, 1613577600, 1613579400, 1613581200, 
1613583000, 1613584800, 1613586600, 1613588400, 1613590200, 1613592000, 
1613593800, 1613595600, 1613597400, 1613599200, 1613601000, 1613602800, 
1613604600, 1613606400, 1613642400, 1613644200, 1613646000, 1613647800, 
1613649600, 1613651400, 1613653200, 1613655000, 1613656800, 1613658600, 
1613660400, 1613662200, 1613664000, 1613665800, 1613667600, 1613669400, 
1613671200, 1613673000, 1613674800, 1613676600, 1613610000, 1613611800, 
1613678400, 1613680200, 1613682000, 1613683800, 1613685600, 1613687400, 
1613689200, 1613691000, 1613613600, 1613615400, 1613608200, 1613617200, 
1613619000, 1613620800, 1613622600, 1613624400, 1613626200, 1613628000, 
1613629800, 1613631600, 1613633400, 1613635200, 1613637000, 1613638800, 
1613640600, 1613692800, 1613728800, 1613730600, 1613732400, 1613734200, 
1613736000, 1613737800, 1613739600, 1613741400, 1613743200, 1613745000, 
1613746800, 1613748600, 1613750400, 1613752200, 1613754000, 1613755800, 
1613757600, 1613759400, 1613761200, 1613763000, 1613696400, 1613698200, 
1613764800, 1613766600, 1613768400, 1613770200, 1613772000, 1613773800, 
1613775600, 1613777400, 1613700000, 1613701800, 1613694600, 1613703600, 
1613705400, 1613707200, 1613709000, 1613710800, 1613712600, 1613714400, 
1613716200, 1613718000, 1613719800, 1613721600, 1613723400, 1613725200, 
1613727000, 1613779200, 1613815200, 1613817000, 1613818800, 1613820600, 
1613822400, 1613824200, 1613826000, 1613827800, 1613829600, 1613831400, 
1613833200, 1613835000, 1613836800, 1613838600, 1613840400, 1613842200, 
1613844000, 1613845800, 1613847600, 1613849400, 1613782800, 1613784600, 
1613851200, 1613853000, 1613854800, 1613856600, 1613858400, 1613860200, 
1613862000, 1613863800, 1613786400, 1613788200, 1613781000, 1613790000, 
1613791800, 1613793600, 1613795400, 1613797200, 1613799000, 1613800800, 
1613802600, 1613804400, 1613806200, 1613808000, 1613809800, 1613811600, 
1613813400, 1613865600, 1613901600, 1613903400, 1613905200, 1613907000, 
1613908800, 1613910600, 1613912400, 1613914200, 1613916000, 1613917800, 
1613919600, 1613921400, 1613923200, 1613925000, 1613926800, 1613928600, 
1613930400, 1613932200, 1613934000, 1613935800, 1613869200, 1613871000, 
1613937600, 1613939400, 1613941200, 1613943000, 1613944800, 1613946600, 
1613948400, 1613950200, 1613872800, 1613874600, 1613867400, 1613876400, 
1613878200, 1613880000, 1613881800, 1613883600, 1613885400, 1613887200, 
1613889000, 1613890800, 1613892600, 1613894400, 1613896200, 1613898000, 
1613899800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    UR = c(89.7, 53.2, 46.9, 45.6, 45.3, 36.4, 36.4, 39.2, 40.4, 
    42.2, 43.8, 45.5, 51.7, 59.8, 65.3, 74.5, 80.7, 85.2, 87.1, 
    87.7, 89.7, 90.6, 91.5, 90.3, 91.5, 91.6, 92.5, 93.4, 93.7, 
    93.2, 92.4, 92, 92.3, 89.7, 92, 92.5, 92.8, 94, 90.8, 84.1, 
    84, 72.1, 70.4, 58.2, 56.4, 42.6, 44.4, 45.1, 92.1, 38.5, 
    42.4, 53.3, 77.9, 80, 75.3, 68.4, 57.6, 49.9, 58.7, 69.5, 
    70.4, 72.9, 72.8, 81, 84.9, 89.7, 91.5, 92.5, 92.5, 93.2, 
    93.3, 92.8, 93.6, 94.1, 94.3, 94, 94, 93.4, 92.2, 93.5, 93.5, 
    92.7, 93.7, 93.8, 93.9, 93.7, 92.1, 87.9, 83.8, 61.2, 41.8, 
    34.3, 39, 34.3, 33.1, 40.7, 92.3, 36.3, 38, 36.4, 40.9, 49, 
    39.7, 44.4, 42, 41.3, 50.4, 54.4, 62.7, 68.3, 72.7, 75.3, 
    79.9, 83.1, 85.1, 85, 85.7, 93.4, 93.7, 85.3, 86.6, 88.8, 
    88.6, 88.5, 88.7, 89.6, 90.4, 93.4, 93.4, 93, 93.7, 93.4, 
    94.2, 94.3, 92.6, 86.8, 82.6, 66.1, 48.9, 44.4, 40.3, 40.6, 
    37.5, 35.6, 91.3, 53.9, 39.1, 38.1, 36.2, 42.3, 43.6, 52.5, 
    66, 79.2, 79.4, 75.3, 78.6, 79.7, 84.3, 84.6, 87.3, 90.3, 
    91.5, 92, 92.8, 91.2, 90.5, 92.5, 92.7, 92.4, 92.6, 92.9, 
    93.3, 93.1, 93.4, 89.1, 88, 91.5, 87.7, 88.2, 89, 90, 88.8, 
    86.5, 83.3, 76.9, 66.3, 61.8, 69, 71.3, 53.9, 54.5, 93.9, 
    71.4, 66.6, 58.1, 58.3, 52.1, 52.2, 54.2, 54.8, 67.8, 69.4, 
    77.1, 82.7, 84, 84.4, 89.1, 92.2, 93.5, 93.6, 94.5, 94.1, 
    94.1, 94.4, 94.3, 94.8, 95, 95.4, 95.3, 94.8, 95.3, 95.3, 
    94.5, 94.5, 93.8, 94.7, 95, 95.1, 95.1, 95, 93.1, 91.8, 90.8, 
    87.7, 81, 74.1, 72.5, 65.5, 71.5, 91.7, 31.2, 29.1, 32.6, 
    33.5, 34.1, 32.9, 32.8, 33.1, 34.4, 34.5, 38.6, 43.7, 51.6, 
    62.4, 71, 78, 80.9, 82.6, 85.3, 86.7, 91.1, 91.5, 87.6, 87.1, 
    88.4, 89.7, 90.6, 91.3, 90.9, 91.7, 92.6, 93.1, 91.2, 93.2, 
    93.5, 93.9, 94.4, 94.4, 92.4, 88.8, 80.7, 62.5, 48.6, 44.2, 
    49.7, 35.7, 30.9, 92.4, 35.3, 34.7, 29.8, 30.7, 30.9, 31.1, 
    30.8, 32, 31.6, 32.1, 35, 40.2, 46.5, 51.8, 64.4, 74.6, 81.6, 
    85.1, 86.9, 87.9, 91.6, 91.1, 89.3, 89.8, 90.2, 89.3, 89.8, 
    90.8, 91.4, 92, 91.6, 90.8, 92.2, 91.8, 92.4, 92, 92.6, 91.8, 
    86.5, 82.4, 78.1, 62.3, 57.1, 48.6, 37.8, 34.2, 32.1, 91.4, 
    29.1, 30.1, 28.5, 29.1, 30.4, 30.9, 31.4, 33.1, 33.8, 34, 
    35.5, 42.5, 47.8, 57.1, 60.5, 67.4, 74.9, 80.5, 83.1, 85.2, 
    91.9, 92.3, 87.3, 87.5, 87.7, 87.3, 87.8, 88.5, 89.2, 90, 
    92.3, 92.6, 91.6, 91.8, 91.4, 91.3, 91.4, 91.6, 89.8, 87.4, 
    81.9, 56.8, 38.8, 34.4, 30.3, 29.4, 29.7, 90.7, 30.9, 28.4, 
    29.1, 30.4, 31.4, 31.7, 32.8, 33.3, 31.8, 34.4, 36.7, 39.7, 
    45.8, 51.9, 59.4, 70.5, 78.2, 82.5, 85.8, 87.6, 91.2, 91.4, 
    87.4, 87.4, 87.4, 88, 88.7, 89.2, 89.8, 90.5, 91.3, 91, 91.1, 
    91.3, 91.6, 91.9, 92.3, 91.6, 89, 85.8, 82.9, 53.2, 41.7, 
    35.7, 32.5, 33.6, 32.7, 91, 31.7, 32.1, 30.8, 31.5, 31.5, 
    30.5, 31.6, 32.2, 31.1, 31.5, 34.8, 40.9, 46.9, 56.1, 61.7, 
    70.4, 77.1, 82, 85.4, 86.8, 91.3, 91.5, 87.6, 87.8, 88.5, 
    88.8, 89, 89.8, 90.3, 90.8, 92, 92.4, 91, 92.7, 92.8, 93, 
    93.1, 93, 91.9, 89.5, 84.4, 56.7, 42.5, 36.2, 36.1, 32.2, 
    30.3, 47.2, 49.4833333333333, 52.7766666666667, 51.7933333333333, 
    53.0833333333333, 50.6833333333333, 37.78, 47.6666666666667, 
    55.24, 51.6766666666667, 51.2766666666667, 48.3566666666667, 
    52.69, 61.7766666666667, 74.4766666666667, 81.7333333333333, 
    85.92, 88.1266666666667, 89.5133333333333, 90.65, 90.5133333333333, 
    90.9033333333333, 91.07, 90.8733333333333, 90.01, 90.8866666666667, 
    90.7633333333333, 89.6933333333333, 41.9066666666667, 40.68, 
    45.5733333333333, 40.99, 43.0833333333333, 43.7666666666667, 
    45.3266666666667, 46.16, 48.4266666666667, 46.57, 42.98, 
    39.26, 45.78, 52.8733333333333, 59.6233333333333, 73.3366666666667, 
    81.71, 86.49, 90.6033333333333, 91.7, 91.5466666666667, 92.77, 
    92.6433333333333, 92.9733333333333, 92.06, 92.5866666666667, 
    92.9466666666667, 92.7233333333333, 92.5866666666667, 92.5066666666667, 
    92.1733333333333, 91.7733333333333, 91.06, 91.75, 92.1866666666667, 
    92.6566666666667, 93.19, 93.4833333333333, 93.4033333333333, 
    91.7033333333333, 87.1233333333333, 80.53, 65.6233333333333, 
    56.73, 58.9133333333333, 53.4333333333333, 46.5733333333333, 
    92.7733333333333, 57.5566666666667, 58.5466666666667, 68.6266666666667, 
    69.9433333333333, 67.64, 65.7933333333333, 63.2433333333333, 
    69.3733333333333, 67.91, 71.94, 69.1466666666667, 72.0033333333333, 
    72.9366666666667, 76.2666666666667, 77.5066666666667, 82.4533333333333, 
    87.1766666666667, 89.9733333333333, 91.2133333333333, 92.1333333333333, 
    92.4233333333333, 92.9266666666667, 92.4533333333333, 92.8733333333333, 
    93.4433333333333, 93.3966666666667, 93.48, 93.7933333333333, 
    93.8933333333333, 94.3666666666667, 93.1066666666667, 93.4866666666667, 
    92.9333333333333, 94.6766666666667, 95.0566666666667, 94.9233333333333, 
    94.9366666666667, 94.85, 95.0966666666667, 94.2033333333333, 
    92.02, 86.6933333333333, 80.46, 76.5966666666667, 72.7466666666667, 
    69.2166666666667, 66.2066666666667, 95.03, 55.59, 45.43, 
    49.52, 47.6466666666667, 46.5833333333333, 39.61, 44.9466666666667, 
    58.5266666666667, 47.2833333333333, 62.0266666666667, 68.0866666666667, 
    64.1466666666667, 63.6733333333333, 73.88, 78.6066666666667, 
    81.2033333333333, 85.0133333333333, 88.6233333333333, 90.5966666666667, 
    91.39, 95.0666666666667, 93.56, 92.2066666666667, 92.5266666666667, 
    91.9433333333333, 92.82, 93.3666666666667, 93.63, 93.9966666666667, 
    94.0533333333333, 93.8966666666667, 94.46, 95.27, 94.0666666666667, 
    94.82, 94.44, 95.0966666666667, 95.37, 95.6766666666667, 
    95.5966666666667, 93.4, 88.7866666666667, 74.3066666666667, 
    58.4233333333333, 59.4133333333333, 60.27, 60.38, 93.17, 
    41.8966666666667, 40.36, 36.25, 39.6833333333333, 36.0033333333333, 
    35.2766666666667, 33.4233333333333, 32.38, 39.68, 38.43, 
    42.43, 44.5833333333333, 49.5733333333333, 64.4833333333333, 
    72.77, 77.1366666666667, 81.0633333333333, 83.67, 86.7433333333333, 
    88.4533333333333, 93.69, 93.3833333333333, 89.3766666666667, 
    88.8166666666667, 88.99, 89.8566666666667, 89.8166666666667, 
    90.1433333333333, 91.0166666666667, 91.3433333333333, 93.5233333333333, 
    94.42, 93.4233333333333, 94.4033333333333, 94.5466666666667, 
    94.9766666666667, 94.6733333333333, 94.4, 94.3066666666667, 
    94.3233333333333, 92.2066666666667, 85.1666666666667, 75.16, 
    60.9833333333333, 52.7466666666667, 47.4533333333333, 45.0766666666667
    )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 
145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 
222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 1435L, 1436L, 
1437L, 1438L, 1439L, 1440L, 1441L, 1442L, 1443L, 1444L, 1445L, 
1446L, 1447L, 1448L, 1449L, 1450L, 1451L, 1452L, 1453L, 1454L, 
1455L, 1456L, 1457L, 1458L, 1459L, 1460L, 1461L, 1462L, 1463L, 
1464L, 1465L, 1466L, 1467L, 1468L, 1469L, 1470L, 1471L, 1472L, 
1473L, 1474L, 1475L, 1476L, 1477L, 1478L, 1479L, 1480L, 1481L, 
1482L, 1483L, 1484L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 1488L, 1489L, 1490L, 
1491L, 1492L, 1493L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 1497L, 1498L, 1499L, 
1500L, 1501L, 1502L, 1503L, 1504L, 1505L, 1506L, 1507L, 1508L, 
1509L, 1510L, 1511L, 1512L, 1513L, 1514L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 
1518L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 1522L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 1526L, 
1527L, 1528L, 1529L, 1530L, 1531L, 1532L, 1533L, 1534L, 1535L, 
1536L, 1537L, 1538L, 1539L, 1540L, 1541L, 1542L, 1543L, 1544L, 
1545L, 1546L, 1547L, 1548L, 1549L, 1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 
1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 1558L, 1559L, 1560L, 1561L, 1562L, 
1563L, 1564L, 1565L, 1566L, 1567L, 1568L, 1569L, 1570L, 1571L, 
1572L, 1573L, 1574L, 1575L, 1576L, 1577L, 1578L, 1579L, 1580L, 
1581L, 1582L, 1583L, 1584L, 1585L, 1586L, 1587L, 1588L, 1589L, 
1590L, 1591L, 1592L, 1593L, 1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 1598L, 
1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 1602L, 1603L, 1604L, 1605L, 1606L, 1607L, 
1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 1612L, 1613L, 1614L, 1615L, 1616L, 
1617L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 1621L, 1622L, 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 
1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 1630L, 1631L, 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 
1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1642L, 1643L, 
1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 1647L, 1648L, 1649L, 1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 
1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 1661L, 
1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 1670L, 
1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1837L, 1838L, 1839L, 1840L, 1841L, 
1842L, 1843L, 1844L, 1845L, 1846L, 1847L, 1848L, 1849L, 1850L, 
1851L, 1852L, 1853L, 1854L, 1855L, 1856L, 1857L, 1858L, 1859L, 
1860L, 1861L, 1862L, 1863L, 1864L, 1865L, 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 
1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 1872L, 1873L, 1874L, 1875L, 1876L, 1877L, 
1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1881L, 1882L, 1883L, 1884L, 1885L, 1886L, 
1887L, 1888L, 1889L, 1890L, 1891L, 1892L, 1893L, 1894L, 1895L, 
1896L, 1897L, 1898L, 1899L, 1900L, 1901L, 1902L, 1903L, 1904L, 
1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 1909L, 1910L, 1911L, 1912L, 1913L, 
1914L, 1915L, 1916L, 1917L, 1918L, 1919L, 1920L, 1921L, 1922L, 
1923L, 1924L, 1925L, 1926L, 1927L, 1928L, 1929L, 1930L, 1931L, 
1932L, 1933L, 1934L, 1935L, 1936L, 1937L, 1938L, 1939L, 1940L, 
1941L, 1942L, 1943L, 1944L, 1945L, 1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 1949L, 
1950L, 1951L, 1952L, 1953L, 1954L, 1955L, 1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 
1959L, 1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 
1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 
1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 
2022L, 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 
2031L, 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 
2040L, 2041L, 2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 
2049L, 2050L, 2051L, 2052L, 2053L, 2054L, 2055L), class = "data.frame")
```

dados para os breaks:

```
dias<-saldo%>%subset(V2=="00:00:00")%>%select(Time,UNIX)
```

script do gráfico (Figura 1):

```
ggplot(exe2,aes(x=Time,y=UR,group=V1))+geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels ="%y-%m-%d %H",breaks=dias$Time)+theme_bw()+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível maneira de resolver o problema é com `facet_*`. O gráfico é divido em três, um para cada grupo. Para isso cria-se uma variável `faceta`. Os `breaks` são omitidos uma vez que `dias$Time` não está na pergunta.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

exe2 %>%
  mutate(faceta = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(exe2$V1) > 1)),
         faceta = paste("Grupo", faceta)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, UR, group = V1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_labels = "%y-%m-%d %H"
    #,
    #breaks = dias$Time
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ faceta, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pois é, até pensei, e ainda omitir os strip, mas como esse é so um exemplo nos dados reais, ficaria o grupo 1 com 30 dias, o 2 com 10, e o 3 com 3, dias, na hora de plotar, a parte do grupo 1 ficaria "espremida" em relação aos demais, eu gostaria de algo com melhor fluidez. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo esforço.

Comment: Substitua o `facet_wrap...` por `facet_grid(~ faceta, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")`. Assim cada faceta terá largura proporcional ao comprimento do eixo X.